# Program is not returning expected pc registry address for buffer overflow

Tags: c, arm, buffer-overflow

Using the following program, I am trying to achieve a buffer overflow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void vuln(){
    char buff[16];
    scanf("%s",buff);
    printf("You entered: %s\n",buff);
}

void secret(){
    printf("You shouldn't be here.");
}

int main(){
    vuln();
    return 0;
}
```

When entering `AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFFGGGGHHHHIIIIJJJJKKKKLLLLMMMM` as the input, the crash log reports that R15 (PC) register contains the value `0x46464644`

My question is why isn't the address `0x46464646` ? How is it going to three F's followed by one D? The expected result should be `0x46464646` because that is where the data should be overwritten.

[image: Crash Log]

Comment: You go out of bounds and have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). That means really *anything* could happen, including producing [nasal demons](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html), or the behavior you see.

Comment: Yet, the issues with cybersecurity leverage the fact that, whatever happens, it happens repeatably.  I for one commend this empirical approach to understanding topics in cybersecurity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ARM instructions are aligned, either on a 2-byte or 4-byte boundary depending on whether they are THUMB or ARM instructions.  This means that the LSb of legal branch targets is always zero.  So ARM took advantage of this, and used the LSb of a branch address (for some branch instructions) to denote whether to switch between ARM and THUMB.

It is most likely that you overwrote the stored LR with 0x46464645 or 0x46464646, and then the processor discarded your LSb (or LS2bs) (potentially using it to select the mode to take when executing code at the destination).

Try changing the last of your 'E' characters or first of your 'F's to something with a recognizable upper-6-bits to test this hypothesis.  (presuming your ARM is running little-endian.)  It's most likely the first 'F' considering ARM's alignment requirements.

**Edit: why are people down-voting this question?  It is both interesting and well-asked.**

Here's a reference to the behavior on branching that mentions the mode switch: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489e/Cihfddaf.html

Comment: Because the obvious answer is `scanf("%15s",buff)` to prevent the buffer overflow in the first place.... (but I will commend you for your answer)

Comment: He's trying to figure out how to launch a buffer overflow.  Not prevent/diagnose one.

Comment: I understand that. Though I don't claim ARM expertise, there should be simple debugging tools that would show the addresses involved (btw, I'm not a downvote here)

Comment: These are useless without the corresponding assembly. In fact these could be said as lacking a [mcve]! The C language construct cannot be reliably exploited, only the assembly version!

Comment: Actually, he was quite clever to use a string with repeating blocks of 4 characters.  It exactly reveals that he has a stored link-register 20 byte up the stack (by the faulting address being composed of the corresponding ASCII characters).  And it gave enough info to answer the question. (You do have to know the ARM ABI, though)